# Difference in behavior parsing unicode in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, unicode, html-parsing, decodeuricomponent

When I run the `JSON.parse` or `decodeURI` directly with the variable (`_`) / regex expression that gives the string, it throws error or does not decode but when I run these functions with the same string in the console, it works. I'm sure I'm missing something stupid but couldn't figure out what.

This is from the debugger console on VS code:

[image]

[image]

`_` comes by parsing some values using regular expression from a html string. `data` is a HTML string that comes from external system. Something like:

```js
const _ = /(?<=customer_data\['some_property'\] = ').*?(?=';)/.exec(data)?.[0] || '{}';
```

I can't figure out even how to approach this issue.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` and `decodeURI()` are *wildly* different.

Comment: I agree but in this use case none of these are working.

Comment: "the variable / regex expression that gives the string" — what does that mean? *What* variable? *What* regex expression? This question does not make any sense.

Comment: What's an example of `data`?

Comment: `data` is a html string coming from external system. I've updated the description mentioning this.

Comment: @Pointy, in this case `variable` is `_` that's logged in the top of the image and the regular expression is `/(?<=customer_data\['some_property'\] = ').*?(?=';)/.exec(data)?.[0]` which yeilds `_`, the variable

Comment: Is your string a literal '\x7b` etc? Because that won't work with JSON.parse. You just have a string that starts with `x` then, not actually an encoded `{`.

Comment: @VLAZ, yes, the string is the one logged in the image. If you see, JSON.parse() does work when I pass that string to it, at the end of the image

Comment: You are ***NOT*** passing the same string. Try logging `_` and what you pass in the end. The string *literal* `"\x7b"` has *content* of `{` and that's what you'd see when you log it. To see the output `\x7b` then that means that's the *content* of the string, and a literal to construct this content is `"\\x7b"` which, if you log, you'd see does not show `{`. Therefore the content in `_` has to be *decoded* before you use it. Which you've shown you do, yet you don't use the output in `JSON.parse`

Comment: @VLAZ `JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(_))` yeilds the same result if that's what you meant by "yet you don't use the output in `JSON.parse`". I've added the screenshot in the description

Comment: Could you try `JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(_.replaceAll('\\x', '%')))` (or `replace(/\\x/g, '%')`)?

Comment: what's the output of `decodeURIComponent(_.replace(/\\x/g, '%'))`?

Comment: Sorry, I tried `replace` and not `replaceAll`, `replaceAll` seems to work. Let me confirm with the full flow that it works

Comment: @Kiran yeah my bad I added `replace` without the `g` option at first, then edited it to say `replaceAll` or `replace(/.../g, ...)`

Comment: @zouabi, if you'd like to add it as an answer, I can mark it as accepted. Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you are trying to parse is already escaped, i.e: `\\x7b\\x222\\x22:\\x22041169082\\x22\\x7d`.

Replace all `\\x`s with a `%` and decode it using [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent):

```js
const _ = '\\x7b\\x222\\x22:\\x22041169082\\x22\\x7d';

console.log(
  decodeURIComponent(_.replace(/\\x/g, '%'))
);
```